# R formattable datatable to shiny

Tags: shiny, rstudio

i have this code that work normally in RStudio
but i wont this in shiny
as.datatable() does not work in shiny with renderFormattable

it says  "no applicable method for 'as.htmlwidget' applied to an object of class "c('datatables', 'htmlwidget')""

## server.R

output$data<-renderFormattable({

```
  df1<-merge(happiness5[,c(1,3)],
             happiness6[,c(1,3)],
             by.x = "Country",
             by.y = "Country")
  colnames(df1)<-c("Country","Happiness Rank 2015","Happiness Rank 2016")
  df1<-df1%>%
    mutate(`Rank Change`=`Happiness Rank 2015`-`Happiness Rank 2016`)
  
  
  formattable(df1,list(
    `Rank Change` = formatter(
      "span",
      style=~formattable::style(color=ifelse(`Rank Change`>0,"green","red")))))%>%
    as.datatable()
},env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `renderFormattable(…)` to `renderDataTable(…)`.

Since you converted the `formattable` to a `datatable` in your last but one row, you need to tell the renderer that it has to deal with a `datatable`.